# MySQL and PHP code allowing empty form field data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have seen many similar questions on this site but I have not yet found a solution for my code. I did use if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {} and the if statements to go along with it to try and stop my script from inserting empty form field data but it hasn't worked yet. Just a note; I am aware of the security flaws in my code. I'm just trying to keep it simple so it will be easier for everyone to help me :) Here's what I have:

```
 <body>

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'bcd_email_app')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

    $query = "INSERT INTO email_subscribers (name, username, email)" .
    "VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$email')";

    mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database');

    echo 'Thanks for subscribing '. $username .'!!<br />';
    echo '<a href="index.php">Go Back</a>';

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $output_form = false;

    //checking that all form fields have been filled out and if not displaying the form with sticky data
    if (empty($name) && (empty($username) && (empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your information for all fields. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
    if (empty($name) && (!empty($username) && (!empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your name. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
    if (!empty($name) && (empty($username) && (!empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your username. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
    if (!empty($name) && (!empty($username) && (empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your email address. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
    if (empty($name) && (empty($username) && (!empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your name and username. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
    if (empty($name) && (!empty($username) && (empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your name and email address. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
    if (!empty($name) && (empty($username) && (empty($email)))) {
        echo 'Please enter your username and email. <br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
} else {
    $output_form = true;
}
if ($output_form) {

    ?>
```

Form Markup Here

```
</body>
```

I also tried to say if name && username && email is not empty like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) && (!empty($_POST['name'])) && (!empty($_POST['username'])) && (!empty($_POST['email']))) {...}
```

with the post submit, and that didn't do anything. Is there a solution? Did I do this totally wrong? lol

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why don't you make the input field required?   

Also the form markup is missing?

Comment: `<input type='text' required>` and you're done

Comment: validate the input fields in client side

Comment: @Irvin No.. you're not done.. you always must to validate data in backend.. I can post data using curl and what happens then?

Comment: OP's main problem is about allowing empty form field data so I just answered it. Security and other measures is surely important but that is not part of his question and he said `I am aware of the security flaws in my code. I'm just trying to keep it simple so it will be easier for everyone to help me`. @MateiMihai

Comment: wonder how long your code will be if there will be 20  form fields :) ?
why you don't count errors ? i.e: if (empty($name)) {$err[] = 'Name required'; }

Comment: required would have worked great too but I was trying to figure out how to get it done with PHP. Thanks for the suggestion... if I didn't want more control over the message, this would have been a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you expect to not insert empty data if you validate after inserting it into db?

First validate the data and show an error if your data is empty and insert it into db only if your validation is successful.

Comment: This was actually very helpful! I ended up creating another if at the end of the empty field checks that checked to make sure none of the fields were empty and if none were then connected to the database. Seems to work great so far. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I use strlen

```
if (strlen($_POST['name']) > 0 and strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){
    //do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 1){
  //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: and why it's better then empty ?

Comment: I have ran into situations where empty did not match.  I do not remember the exact scenario. I just don't like the idea if isset because the var is set,its just set to nothing. it may be the same as using empty, i just have found more success with strlen

Comment: consider this: strlen(0)
and I'm talking about empty not isset.

Comment: Empty is the same as isset and var === false.  Strlen(0) matches var=== false, but fails in isset.

Comment: strlen(0) === 1, since 0 converts to string "0" and it's length is 1, it's not correct behavior if you think that 0 should pass ?(ofcourse it depends..,), that's why you should use EMPTY, forget about isset

Comment: If the string "0" is passed, it is both isset and not false. Empty will fail.  Strlen will also fail. The OP wanted to make sure post had at least 1 piece of data in it.  Other validations rules will need to be written to test for more than > 1 piece of data.